# Should I ask my employer about my visa status since it has been 10 days the last we communicated?

Tags: job-search, work-environment, job-offer, employer, visa

I am selected in UAE as a software engineer and has signed the job offer, also I send him the scanned copies of all the required attested documents along with the hard copy of my attested degree via courier.

He told me that my employment visa is under process now and will inform me asap but it has been 9 days since then and I haven't communicated with him

Should I contact him and ask about my visa or wait for their email. I sometimes get negative thoughts if something gets delayed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, absolutely reach out to get an update. If anything you should get a timeframe of how long the process should take.